# using "ancestor" in xpath with relative path

Tags: java, xml, xpath, relative-path, ancestor

I have an xml similar to

```
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <GenericData>
            <Data>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <Name>ABC</Name>
            </Data>
        </GenericData>
        <DepartmentData>
            <SubDepartment>
                <DeptID>12</DeptID>
                <DeptName>IT</DeptName>
            </SubDepartment>
        </DepartmentData>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <GenericData>
            <Data>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <Name>XYZ</Name>
            </Data>
        </GenericData>
        <DepartmentData>
            <SubDepartment>
                <DeptID>13</DeptID>
                <DeptName>HR</DeptName>
            </SubDepartment>
        </DepartmentData>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

My problem is to get DeptID based on name. I am able fetch the same using:

```
//Data/Name[text()="ABC"]/ancestor::Employee/DepartmentData/SubDepartment/DeptName/text()
```

Need a solution to use relative path after ancestor something like:

```
//Data/Name[text()=\"ABC\"]/ancestor::Employee/*/DeptName/text()
```

Removing DepartmentData/SubDepartment with * i.e. using a relative path.

**Note:** My actual xml is too complex and writing whole path is not feasible. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to set the predicate on the lowest node that is a shared ancestor of both the name and the id, and access the target data from there :

```
/Employees/Employee[./GenericData/Data/Name/text() = "ABC"]/DepartmentData/SubDepartment/DeptID/text()
```

This looks up employees, keep only those (the one) with the relevant Name, then extracts their (its) DeptID.

That doesn't require a full path, e.g. you can use `//Employee` if you want. That said using `//` can have a significant impact on performances and it's rarely necessary to use.

Answer (score 0):

If `DeptName` is unique for `Employee` you may just use `//`:

```
//Data/Name[text()="ABC"]/ancestor::Employee//DeptName/text()
```

Or the same with the approach by @Aaron which I think is more intuitive. Also, if you can use XPath 2.0 you may store `Employee` or other staff in a variable for better readability, as you say your XML ist quite complex:

```
let $Employee := /Employees/Employee[GenericData/Data/Name/text() = "ABC"]
return
$Employee//DeptName/text()
```